# select multiple columns by value

Tags: python, pandas

i want to select two columns sku and month by value samsung and january

```
print(field)
print(values)
output:
  ['SKUDESC', 'Full_month']`enter code here`
  ['samsung', 'January']
df[(field[0]) == values[0]) & (field[1]) == values[1]]
```

it is showing key error

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
df[(field.column_name == 'samsung') & (field.column_name == 'January')]
```